# Update DataContext with newest database values

Tags: c#, datacontext

I have a winforms client app, that runs with a datacontext.
I'm now running into some kind of concurrency problems, cause each of my clients have their own datacontext running, and when made changes, they store the changes in the database. But when User A make a changes in Object_1, and store the changes in the database, User B can't see these changes made on object_1 by User A.

- What I want is, to update Object_1 with values from database, each time a user opens object_1.

I have try'd to use the DataContext.Refresh method, but it seems that it doesn't update the object with the database values.
Heres a code sample:

```
    public void updateObj(object obj)
    {
        if (hvilken is Apartment)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        if (hvilken is Customer)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any best in practice way, to update the DataContext with the newest values in the database?

Comment: Please don't swallow exceptions. If that code `throw`s, it is throwing *for a reason*

Comment: I'm debugging the code, and the method ain't throwing exceptions. My test case is as follows:
1. Change values to Obj1 on Machine A and save to db
2. View Obj1 on Machine B
On machine B I should now see the values typed from Machine A, but I'm still getting the "old" values from before Machine A changed the value. Even tho I'm using the Refresh method without any exceptions :/

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContext.Refresh` mode is not generic, so there is little benefit in your special-casing; and the empty `catch` is simply bad practice (it could indeed be why you don't know why it isn't working: it might be trying to tell you, but you are ignoring it). So in a "best practice" way, you would simplify:

```
public void UpdateObject(object obj)
{
    DataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, obj);
}
```

If it doesn't work, it will probably `throw` to tell you why not.

Comment: Well, I totally agree that empty brackets what so ever, is bad practice. But thats not the catch in this situation, since I'm running in debug mode, and the method doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: But it doesn't update the associated navigation collection property which maps to another table. It is updating only the properties which map to the column of the table to which the current Entity points to. Is there a way out of this in Linq to Sql?